# How to change the intergenartion time in Simevents in Matlab.

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to change the inter generation time between different entities in simevents entity generator. For example for first 1000 entities i want to have inter generation time of 1 sec , then next 1000 entities i want to have a intergeneration time of 2.3 sec etc. Here i also want to set the intergeneration time to be random not fixed. Can anyone guide me how can i do that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can see a nexus with a mathematical problem that would make this on-topic for Math.SE.  The guideline is for software questions (involving software "used by mathematicians", and Matlab satisfies that part of the criteria) to be about solving a math problem.  Here you want to do a particular thing, but it seems more about the Simulink machinery than about any underlying math problem.  We avoid trying to duplicate the support services of the software maintainers, in this case a commercial proprietary enterprise with extensive support in documentation and user forums.

Comment: See for example the [Mathworks help page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simevents/ug/specifying-intergeneration-times-for-entities.html) on various ways to specify intergeneration times for entities.